# Oracle query data using rownum to be ambiguously

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I would like to query my `Oracle` data using `ROWNUM`.

Format like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT
    ACTIVITYNAME, rownum AS rnum
    FROM
(
    SELECT ACTIVITYNAME
    FROM
    WA_GA_TBL_ACTIVITY
    ORDER BY ACTIVITYNAME)
    WHERE rownum <= 20
)
WHERE  rnum > 10
```

And what I want on my full query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT
    A.ACTIVITYID,
    A.ACTIVITYNAME,
    A.GROUPID_FK,
    TO_CHAR(A.ACTIVITYDATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS ACTIVITYDATES,
    U.GROUPID_FK,
    U.FIRSTNAME,
    U.LASTNAME,
    U.USERAVATAR
    FROM
    WA_GA_TBL_ACTIVITY A,
    WA_GA_TBL_USERS U
    WHERE
    A.USERID_FK = U.USERID AND
    A.USERID_FK != '" . $getUserID . "' AND
    (A.GROUPID_FK = '" . $getGroupIDFK . "' OR (A.GROUPID_FK_TO LIKE ('%" . $getGroupIDFK . "%')) OR ((A.USERID_FK_TO IS NOT NULL AND A.USERID_FK_TO = '" . $getUserID . "'))) AND
    A.ACTIVITYID IN(SELECT ACTIVITYID_FK FROM WA_GA_TBL_ACCESSACTIVITY WHERE USERID_FK = '" . $getUserID . "') AND
    ROWNUM <= 20
    ORDER BY A.ACTIVITYDATE DESC
)
WHERE ROWNUM <= 10
```

When I try to run the query it show me error: `ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined`

Comment: please show table DDL

Comment: I'm probably suffering from partial blindness, but - as far as I can tell, none of those two queries would return ORA-00918. Could you, please, post SQL*Plus session which shows what you're saying?

Comment: Hi @all, please have a look on this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7bb79/2

Answer (score 0):

The inner query has 2 "groupid_fk" you'll need to alias one of those off to some other name for the outer query to work.  I formatted below so lines 8 and 10.

Also not sure what language this is but becareful with SQL Injection on lines 19,21,22,26,37

```
SQL> format buffer
  1  SELECT
  2      *
  3  FROM
  4      (
  5          SELECT
  6              a.activityid,
  7              a.activityname,
  8              a.groupid_fk,
  9              TO_CHAR(a.activitydate,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS activitydates,
 10              u.groupid_fk,
 11              u.firstname,
 12              u.lastname,
 13              u.useravatar
 14          FROM
 15              wa_ga_tbl_activity a,
 16              wa_ga_tbl_users u
 17          WHERE
 18              a.userid_fk = u.userid
 19              AND a.userid_fk != '" . $getUserID . "'
 20              AND (
 21                  a.groupid_fk = '" . $getGroupIDFK . "'
 22                  OR ( a.groupid_fk_to LIKE ( '%" . $getGroupIDFK . "%' ) )
 23                  OR (
 24                      (
 25                          a.userid_fk_to IS NOT NULL
 26                          AND a.userid_fk_to = '" . $getUserID . "'
 27                      )
 28                  )
 29              )
 30              AND a.activityid IN (
 31                  SELECT
 32                      activityid_fk
 33                  FROM
 34                      wa_ga_tbl_accessactivity
 35                  WHERE
 36                      userid_fk = '" . $getUserID . "'
 37              )
 38              AND ROWNUM <= 20
 39          ORDER BY
 40              a.activitydate DESC
 41      )
 42  WHERE
 43*     ROWNUM <= 10
SQL>
```